# PHP, Yii framework: can't create post (users, roles)

Tags: php, yii, yii2, rbac

I have tried implementing RBAC in Yii2. I have followed this tutorial: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html#rbac but now I have a problem. I have logged in with an "admin" account (id=1), but I cannot create a new *item*, even though I should be able to. Here are my files:

```
public function up()
    {
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

        // add "viewPost" permission
        $viewPost= $auth->createPermission('viewPost');
        $viewPost->description = 'View a post';
        $auth->add($viewPost);

        // add "createPost" permission
        $createPost = $auth->createPermission('createPost');
        $createPost->description = 'Create a post';
        $auth->add($createPost);

        // add "updatePost" permission
        $updatePost = $auth->createPermission('updatePost');
        $updatePost->description = 'Update post';
        $auth->add($updatePost);

        // add "viewer" role and give this role the "viewPost" permission
        $viewer = $auth->createRole('viewer');
        $auth->add($viewer);
        $auth->addChild($viewer, $viewPost);

        // add "author" role and give this role the "createPost" permission
        $author = $auth->createRole('author');
        $auth->add($author);
        $auth->addChild($author, $createPost);

        // add "admin" role and give this role the "updatePost" permission
        // as well as the permissions of the "author" role
        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $auth->add($admin);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $updatePost);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $author);

// add the rule
$rule = new \app\rbac\AuthorRule;
$auth->add($rule);

// add the "updateOwnPost" permission and associate the rule with it.
$updateOwnPost = $auth->createPermission('updateOwnPost');
$updateOwnPost->description = 'Update own post';
$updateOwnPost->ruleName = $rule->name;
$auth->add($updateOwnPost);

// "updateOwnPost" will be used from "updatePost"
$auth->addChild($updateOwnPost, $updatePost);

// allow "author" to update their own posts
$auth->addChild($author, $updateOwnPost);

        // Assign roles to users. 1 and 2 are IDs returned by IdentityInterface::getId()
        // usually implemented in your User model.
        $auth->assign($admin, 1);
    }
```

In the *item* view, I wanted to hide the "create" button for users who can't create items:

```
<?php if (\Yii::$app->user->can('createPost')) : ?>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Item'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

but the button is not here.

I'm a complete beginner with PHP and Yii and have no idea why this doesn't work.

**Edit:**

This is my `ItemController`:

```
  <?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use app\models\Item;
use app\models\ItemSearch;
use yii\web\Controller;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;
//use yii\filters\VerbFilter;
use yii\filters\AccessControl;

/**
 * ItemController implements the CRUD actions for Item model.
 */
class ItemController extends Controller
{
    public function behaviors()
    {
        //return [
            //'verbs' => [
                //'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
                //'actions' => [
                    //'delete' => ['post'],
                //],
            //],
        //];
return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['index'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['view'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['create'],
                    'roles' => ['admin', 'author'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['update'],
                    'roles' => ['admin', 'author'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
    }

    /**
     * Lists all Item models.
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $searchModel = new ItemSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest)
{
$this->redirect(Yii::$app->homeUrl . 'login');
}
else
{
        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
}
    }

    /**
     * Displays a single Item model.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $providerHistory = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $model->histories,
        ]);
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'providerHistory' => $providerHistory,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Item model.
     * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @return mixed
     */
public function actionCreate()
{
        $model = new Item();

        if ($model->loadAll(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->saveAll()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('create', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
}

    /**
     * Updates an existing Item model.
     * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->loadAll(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->saveAll()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes an existing Item model.
     * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'index' page.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->findModel($id)->deleteWithRelated();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Export Item information into PDF format.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function actionPdf($id) {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $providerHistory = new \yii\data\ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $model->histories,
        ]);

        $content = $this->renderAjax('_pdf', [
            'model' => $model,
            'providerHistory' => $providerHistory,
        ]);

        $pdf = new \kartik\mpdf\Pdf([
            'mode' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            'format' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            'destination' => \kartik\mpdf\Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'content' => $content,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            'cssInline' => '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
            'options' => ['title' => \Yii::$app->name],
            'methods' => [
                'SetHeader' => [\Yii::$app->name],
                'SetFooter' => ['{PAGENO}'],
            ]
        ]);

        return $pdf->render();
    }


    /**
     * Finds the Item model based on its primary key value.
     * If the model is not found, a 404 HTTP exception will be thrown.
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Item the loaded model
     * @throws NotFoundHttpException if the model cannot be found
     */
    protected function findModel($id)
    {
        if (($model = Item::findOne($id)) !== null) {
            return $model;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
        }
    }

    /**
    * Action to load a tabular form grid
    * for History
    * @author Yohanes Candrajaya <moo.tensai@gmail.com>
    * @author Jiwantoro Ndaru <jiwanndaru@gmail.com>
    *
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function actionAddHistory()
    {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            $row = Yii::$app->request->post('History');
            if((Yii::$app->request->post('isNewRecord') && Yii::$app->request->post('_action') == 'load' && empty($row)) || Yii::$app->request->post('_action') == 'add')
                $row[] = [];
            return $this->renderAjax('_formHistory', ['row' => $row]);
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'The requested page does not exist.'));
        }
    }
}
```

and my item/create.php view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;


/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Item */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Create Item');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => Yii::t('app', 'Item'), 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="item-create">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?= $this->render('_form', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]) ?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some views are organized in a common part  that is stored tipically in `_form.php` partial view, so you shoud check in _form.php partial views for th code  you need, (in the same \views\yuormodel_form.php)   and extend the behavior with you rbac condition

```
<?php if (\Yii::$app->user->can('createPost')) : ?>
    <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Item'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

In your create.php  view  as you can see  here

```
   <?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
   ]) ?>
```

is rendered  a (common) view  _form

inside the _form.php  near the end you should find this code for create )or update) button

if you want enable the button for Admin role you should  add the check eg:this way

```
<div class="form-group">
    if (\Yii::$app->user->can('admin')){
      <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update',
          ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-warning' : 'btn btn-warning']) ?>
  }
</div>
```

Comment: The code where the button is defined isn't in _form.php.

Comment: then update your question and add  the view invoke by the actiion you are using ..

Comment: i don't see any action  in your controller ..  if you have not action  .. how you invoke the view  that contain the create button ????

Comment: I've added my ItemController. Now this works: the createItem page is only available to admin and author roles, which is good. But still, the condition for showing that button is not true for admin.

Comment: OK  .. now update you question and add  your views/item/create.php view  .. please

Comment: I've added the view